# Error handling media images in tamplate tagging Django Python

Tags: python, django, media

I feel I am overlooking something small, but I am trying to use template tagging display uploaded media files for clothing items:

**INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'apparelapp',
    'import_export',
]
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = "MEDIA_DIR"
```

**models.py**

```
class Uniform(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=11)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length = 6)
    size = models.CharField(choices=CLOTHES_SIZE, max_length=4, blank=True)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, max_length=15, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uniforms/')
```

**html**

```
  <div class="row wow fadeIn">
    {% for item in uniform %}
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="view overlay">
                    <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="Oh no!">
                    <a>
                        <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <label>
                        <h5>{{ item.description }}</h5>
                    </label>
                    <h5>
                        {% if item.description %}
                        <strong>
                            <label for="">{{ item.category }}</label>
                        </strong>
                    </h5>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Even inspecting the page I get the following: [image: image url inspection]

The path all looks right to me, even the `settings.py` set up and uploaded `image` object path of my `Uniform` model. Am I missing something? 
I have looked at some other posts and saw a reccomendation in the `urls.py` to include:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
...
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Still no luck

Comment: can you write your  INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: added the installed apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

There is no `MEDIA_DIR` (unlike `STATICFILES_DIRS`), and you should also set the `MEDIA_ROOT` to a **string**, not a list.

Comment: The error was running the root as a list rather than a string!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to make sure that all these steps are done:

- "django.contrib.staticfiles" is included in your INSTALLED_APPS
- Define STATIC_URL in your settings `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
- Using     `{% load staticfiles %}` in your templates

To make sure it's work correctly:
   *try to open* http:localhost:8000/static/media/your_image.png
You should see only the image.

Comment: I have ```{%load staticfiles%}``` in my template, ```STATIC_URL = '/static/'``` in settings, and have the necessary installed apps